# Error while importing module app using from Flask.app import db

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, python-import

I'm new to flask, and have problem with importing db while running from python console/cmd.

I'm facing this error :

```
In[67]: os.getcwd()
Out[67]: 'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Python\\Flask'
In[68]: os.listdir()
Out[68]: 
['app',
 'app.db',
 'config.py',
 'Flask.py',
 'migrations',
 'venv',
 '__init__.py',
 '__pycache__']

In[69]: from Flask.app.models import User,Post
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-69-dca3714f084d>", line 1, in <module>
    from Flask.app.models import User,Post
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\Python\Flask\app\models.py", line 1, in <module>
    from Flask.app import db
ImportError: cannot import name 'db' from 'Flask.app' (C:\Users\Desktop\Python\Flask\app\__init__.py)
```

The tree of my project :

```
Flask/
  app/
    __init__.py
    forms.py
    models.py
    routes.py
  __init__.py
  config.py
  Flask.py
```

Flask/**init**.py

app/**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask
from Flask.config import Config
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

from Flask.app import routes, models
```

app/models.py

```
from Flask.app import db
from datetime import datetime


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User {}>'.format(self.username)
```

When running flask run via command it's working fine. But I when I'm trying to run via python console or cmd I'm not able to run successfully.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

there is a problem when importing module fix this....

inside Flask remove the __init_.py here u didnt want a init file.if the Flask folder is the root folder others are sub folders inside it I guess your main file is Flask.py. So
change the

```
from Flask.app import db
```

to

```
from app import db
```

considering  db is declared inside app/init.py

Comment: after removing Flask/__init__.py I'm getting error :

>>> from app import db
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\Python\Flask\app\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from Flask.config import Config
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\Python\Flask\Flask.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .app import app
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
>>>

Comment: srry it looks like u are using config.py content inside flask.py.....inthat case put the config.py file inside app folder and  change the ``` from Flask.config import  ``` to from app.config import

Comment: finaly only the main source file or in ur case Flask.py file should be out side and others should be inside app folder....restructure the code importing according to that

Comment: thanks, I restructure as you asked,  but content for Flask.py is from .app import app, which is giving error when doing flask run :  
File "C:\Users\I505412\Desktop\Python\Flask\Flask.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .app import app
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package