# Flask run giving error after setting FLASK_APP not before

Tags: python, flask

When running `flask` run it's running fine till `FLASK_APP` variable is not set, but it gives `error` when I set `FLASK_APP` variable.

Error code is attached below.

```
(venv) (base) C:\Users\Desktop\Python\Flask>flask run
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

(venv) (base) C:\Users\Desktop\Python\Flask>echo %FLASK_APP%
%FLASK_APP%

(venv) (base) C:\Users\Desktop\Python\Flask>set FLASK_APP=Flask.py

(venv) (base) C:\Users\Desktop\Python\Flask>echo %FLASK_APP%
Flask.py

(venv) (base) C:\Users\Desktop\Python\Flask>flask run
 * Serving Flask app "Flask.py"
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]

Error: While importing "Flask", an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\desktop\python\flask\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\Python\Flask\Flask.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .app import app, db
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package


(venv) (base) C:\Users\Desktop\Python\Flask>
```

Also,how flask is able to identify which python file to run if FLASK_APP variable is not set ?

Comment: Show your main file for this flask app, and read carefully the error. Seems that you have problems with imports... and second thing I dont think that Flask.py is a good name for a main app file.

Comment: please refer to this question for file and directory structure : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59505046/error-while-importing-module-app-using-from-flask-app-import-db

Comment: Ok, so comapre this "from .app import app, db" and reply from that thread you paste. try remove that "." from import.
Explanation of relative imports you can find here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3

Comment: it worked, but in pycharm it's showing in red underline and it's running without any error, any idea why it's showing red underline for the statement from app import db

Comment: do not trust pycharm, test this with interpreter.. I learn that pycharm sometimes has problems with imports, but interpreter doesn't. and if it's free edition of pycharm it doesn't have native support  for flask (as far as I remember)